# Buefy not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, bulma

I want to put a simple buefy checkbox in a login page but it's not showing (it's shows just the text "Remember me").I want to use buefy with Laravel, and bulma of course.  I already try to change the versions but it's not working. 
Login page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div id="app">

<div class="columns m-t-75">
    <div class="column is-one-third is-offset-one-third">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header-title">
                <h1 class="title" style="font-weight: 100">Log in</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="label">Email Adress</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="label">Password</label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="password" class="input" name="password" id="password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <b-checkbox name="remember">Remember me</b-checkbox>

                <button class="button is-success is-outlined is-fullwidth">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

@endsection
```

Footer

```
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Buefy from 'buefy'

Vue.use(Buefy);
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "buefy": "^0.5.3",
    "bulma": "^0.5.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
},
"dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have to bind your **#app** div like after

```
require('./bootstrap')
window.Vue = require('vue')
import Buefy from 'buefy'
Vue.use(Buefy)

//Must have to bind this to work with VUE js
const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app'
});
```

You've to know that Buefy uses `Vue js`. And in Vue it must need to wrap the whole document.

> **You have to create a new vue instance with wrapping the div #app**.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I followed your suggestion here, but I still can't get the checkbox to display

Comment: If checkbox is not there, that means in that file Vue js has not included. You can install Vue Dev tools Extension and check if vue is installed or not on that page first.

Comment: I have Vue Dev tool installed and vue is enabled on the page. However when I go to the vue panel I see no components listed apart from the Root component

Comment: I had faced the same issue once. Look at your master.blade.php or nav.blade.php. The <div id="app"> ---- Full page --- </div> But, I hope your app id is finished before that checkbox. Look at the Dev tools and check that app div has finished before that Buefy Checkbox. Modify this app wrapper div.

Comment: The app id is finished in my master.blade.php file. I need the checkbox in my Login.blade.php file and I have included the master file at the top of the login file and it still does not work. However if I put the checkbox anywhere inside the master.blade.php file it works. This is not what I wanted, I need the checkbox in the Login file

Comment: Then in the login file wrap the whole div and create a vue instance only for login page that don't extend master and their use buefy like before.. That's it. Why can't you do that now?

Comment: I took a closer look at the code, it turns out there was an extra div tag in the master.blade.php. I removed it and everything is working fine now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add vue component to **app.js** file. for eg:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Buefy from 'buefy';

Vue.use('Buefy');

Vue.component(Buefy.Checkbox.name, Buefy.Checkbox);
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  }
});
```